# AngularJS value {{expression}} works for <input> but not for <textarea>?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Trying to learn AngularJS and reading the AngularJS documentation on <'textarea> did little to enlighten me.

Can someone explain why expressions won't work with <'textarea>, and show how to make the <'textarea> calculate and display the expression properly like the <'input>?

*BONUS:* When I change the text in <'input value={{fullName()}}>, it refuses to refresh after then changing the text in the other inputs for "firstName" and "lastName". How do I make it so that the "fullName" will always revert back to properly being "firstName + last Name" even if it gets changed?

```js
var app = angular.module('ngapp', []);

app.controller("ngctrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.person = {firstName:"Bob",lastName:"Smith"};
  $scope.fullName = function() {
    return $scope.person.firstName + " " + $scope.person.lastName;
  }
});
```

```css
html,body {
  margin: 4;
  font-family: monospace;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;}

input {
  margin: 4 0 16;
  width: 200;
  font-family: inherit;}

textarea {
  margin: 4 0 16;
  width: 200;
  height: 100;
  font-family: inherit;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ngapp" ng-controller="ngctrl">
      First Name: <br><input title='First Name' ng-model='person.firstName'><br>
      Last Name: <br><input title='Last Name' ng-model='person.lastName'><br>
      Full Name: <br><input title='Full Name (works for input)' value={{fullName()}}></textarea><br>
      Full Name: <br><textarea title='Full Name (does not work for textarea)' value={{fullName()}}></textarea>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

`<textarea title='Full Name (does not work for textarea)' value={{fullName()}}></textarea>`

to

`<textarea title='Full Name (does not work for textarea)' >{{fullName()}}</textarea>`

Because `textarea` doesn't have a value as other input elements does

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation Mr_Perfect.

That makes sense to me because <'textarea> has a closing tag whereas <'input> does not.